# How can I create a loop that can get 6 levels of parents?

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on this page concept of pedigree. How can I foreach or create a loop that can get 6 levels of parents, for example `name= 1 ; nfather=2; nmohter = 3` and the loop continue to get or consider `nfather` as a `name = 2` and get his parents.

```
CREATE TABLE `horses` ( 
`horse_id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`horse_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`horse_sire` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`horse_dam` int(10) DEFAULT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`horse_id`),
KEY `FKsire` (`horse_sire`),
KEY `FKdam` (`horse_dam`),
CONSTRAINT `FKdam` FOREIGN KEY (`horse_dam`) REFERENCES `horses` (`horse_id`),
CONSTRAINT `FKsire` FOREIGN KEY (`horse_sire`) REFERENCES `horses` (`horse_id`)
)
```

Comment: you can do it with a stored procedure in mysql to get all parents till parents are both NULL or level 6 is reached , or you get the complete horse table and build in php a recursive loop. I would prefer a stored procedure. But you should choose the language where you feel comfortable building recursive loops.

Comment: (1) Which version of MySQL are you using? (2) Do you want the hierarchy for the father, for the mother, or both?

Comment: im looking for a script php that can , i have try but with multiples query, i dont know how to do it simply if some body can give mee a solution

Comment: https://www.pedigreequery.com/har    this is the exemple im looking to do like

Comment: Pls share what you have tried and where you got stuck with it. At the moment your question reads as gimme the solution from scratch.